# jQuery Ajax return multiple data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am using jQuery AJAX to return a string from PHP which consists of some JavaScript, PHP and HTML.

I can successfully do this with the following code:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html");
echo $content;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
}).done(function(result) {

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

The problem I have now is that I want to return some other simple values along this string as well.

But if I use `json_encode` to send an array of these values, it will break my string and won't be successful.

How could I send one value as string (without `json_encode`) and some other values with `json_encode`? (so I don't `json_encode` my string)

EDIT1:

Here is formatting issue 1:

```
return 'autoOpenPopup: '.!empty($options["autoOpenPopup"]) ? $this->int_to_bool($options["autoOpenPopup"]) : $this->int_to_bool(false) . PHP_EOL .';
```

2:

```
return '.!isset($options["popupInit"]) ?

                $playerId.' = jQuery("#'.$wrapperId.'").hap(settings);

            ':'

                if(hasLocalStorage){

                    if(!localStorage.getItem("hap_popup_fixed")){
                        '.$playerId.' = jQuery("#'.$wrapperId.'").hap(settings);
                    }
                }else{
                    '.$playerId.' = jQuery("#'.$wrapperId.'").hap(settings);  
                }
```

Comment: What about put your string into the array then `json_encode` both?

Comment: I tried json_encode just on my string and it breaks. Putting it in array doesnt seem to change anything: http://pastie.org/10907465

Comment: Well, you should post the actual code to find what makes it break.

Comment: I edited my post with some data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to `json_encode` your data and string together;

```
$data = array('some', 'array', 'elements');

$string = 'my string';

$data2 = array('more', 'data');
```

Then you combine all of them in one array:

```
$result  = array();
$result['data1'] = $data;
$result['string'] = $string;
$result['data2'] = $data2;
```

Finally `json_encode` the array:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then you read the result in JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
}).done(function(result) {
  var jsonResult = $.parseJSON
  var data1 = result.data;
  var data2 = jsonResult.data2;
  var str = jsonResult.string;

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: I tried json_encode just on my string and it breaks. (I guess because its long mix of php, html, javascript)

Comment: could you share the string with us to take a look?

Comment: I will also include the code to read the data based on my example

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data, true);
```

and in your `$.ajax({...dataType:'json'});`